# What are good linguistic arguments for keeping heterographic homophones?

Tags: historical-linguistics, grammar, orthography

While having a discussion with a friend who oft malapropriates their/there/they're, and to/too/two, he maintains the position that he has a:

> "disbelief that the current system is the best one"

He contends that all that is *necessary* is a single word, say, 'ther', that will accommodate all the uses and that since the context can be gained from a spoken conversation, that a "better system", in his view, would be a system with just the single option - essentially, collapse all homophones into single words with the same orthography, but with combined definitions.

I don't share this perspective; I find the written word to be a superior form of language than spoken, and detest the bastardization of linguistic rules by people who can't be bothered to proofread and follow grammatic and syntactical rules.

My sentiments aside; what specific **reasons** are there to persist variant spellings of homophones?

He's also made reference to the supposed 'inefficiency' of having to learn and use the variant homophones:

> "I do not refuse to learn, I just will not go out of my way to re-type, or proof read something when I feel it reasonable that it will be understood. Also, I feel that its requirement is not necessary and the rules should be amended to simply and expedite conversation."

So - what are good linguistic reasons to retain the heterographic homophones?

Comment: I think this is a much better fit for Linguistics than here—it’s not really about English as such, after all. French has much the same problem, as do many other languages, and the arguments for or against are much the same in most languages. Flagging for migration to Linguistics.

Comment: (Incidentally, the written word is **always** secondary to the spoken word; whether it can ever be superior is a matter of whether you believe a derivative can ever be superior to the original. In this particular case, I would certainly argue that it isn't. The written word is an impoverished dumbing-down of the spoken word with all its subtleties, intonations, body language, etc. There are many aspects to the spoken word that are impossible to accurately represent in writing; the opposite is not the case.)

Comment: How do you feel about dangling participles (gentle josh from a linguist)?

Comment: There aren't any linguistic reasons. Your friend is right and you are wrong. The English spelling system is terrible at representing the modern language. It's like walking over the Sydney Bridge -- good exercise but not a very efficient way to move traffic. Not only that, it makes distinctions that nobody makes natively, like apostrophe's and _they're/there/their; it's/its;_ etc. In speech these are not distinguished and we always understand perfectly, so why should we hafta spell them differently? Clearly we dont, which is why they are such common "mistakes".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I clearly believe derivative works can be superior to the originals; cars today are superior to Model Ts by every metric available, yet are derivative works. Evolution is a whole chain of derivatives being better adapted for survival than their ancestors. Further, large charts, tables, very long lists, and figures like ASCII art are impossible to accurately represent in speaking, to name a few examples.

Comment: @jlawler could you add a full answer and elaborate, please? Is the only purpose of the writing to represent native modern speech, in your perspective? As a retired linguistics professor, would you have taken no issue with people writing 'words that sound the same when spoken' in place of others for your assignments? What could be some vestiges of reasons, and your challenges to them? Finally, how could one go about challenging the grammatical rules should they be so inclined?

Comment: Depends on what the assignment was. We have to teach adult native speakers what the actual sounds of their language are, and then train them to transcribe them. This is something that's handled in grade school most places in the world; but Anglophone schools don't do that. As for "derivative" -- cars are all technology, like writing, and that changes fast. But language is not technology; it's evolved, and evolution does **not** result in organisms that are better adapted than their ancestors -- it results in organisms that are adapted to the **current** environment. Period. Like language.

Comment: I meant to imply that; but said more precisely, evolution produces changes over time, and through natural selection those that are greater adapted to their current environment survive, those that are maladapted perish. It would be more precise to say evolution **can** produce superior products for a given environment. There are, of course, also some examples of further revisions of technology being inferior to their progenitors. That aside; would you not correct a Ph.D. thesis or essay using their/there/they're 'improperly'?

Comment: @Ehryk Correcting a thesis is rather irrelevant to the discussion. Of course, anyone would correct mistakes like that, because **there are certain rules** or **conventions** that are expected to be followed  in order for the thesis to be accepted. That is the tradition. But at the same time, it has little to do with **linguistics** - after all, prescriptive rules like that are created by people, they are not borne by the language (which is correct, _endeavour_ or _endeavor_, and why not _indever_ or even _indevr_? And how about _invizij_).

Comment: Why is thesis correction irrelevant to the discussion? Why should (or should not) the rules and conventions apply in some contexts and not others? Based on the right pane of the wikipedia article for [Linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistics), graphemics, syntax and orthography are subsets of Linguistics, so how how would their/there/they're have little to do with linguistics? Is it your position that they are separate from linguistics?

Comment: Where do I say that _rules and conventions should (or should not) apply in some contexts and not others_? If there is a convention saying we have to distinguish between **their/there/they're**, it just has to be followed, quite logically. And, of course, if the convention says that all three should be spelt, say, **ther**, then again, it just has to be followed.
As to whether I consider orthography **part of linguistics**, that could be another topic for discussion, but no, I don't, _strictu sensu_. I do consider it _connected_, however. Admittedly, my view might be a bit too _narrow_.

Comment: Ah, well in absence of the existence of orthography.stackexchange.com, this is the best fit for the question of orthography in the current set of stack exchange sites. Would the convention not just be 'written English conventions'? Why would they apply in theses, and not in, say, Facebook posts written in English?

Comment: @Ehryk I am confused. What you are getting at? If a nationwide reform makes things easier and more efficient, I don't see why even Facebook users should avoid it, unless they come up with something better. After all, Facebook communication, especially among friends, is not restricted the way academic discourse or any other (semi-)official written communication is. It is often the casual, unofficial communication which gives you glimpses of the possible directions future reforms could take.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26901/discussion-between-pavel-jetusek-and-ehryk), as it is getting a bit too long. Shall we?

Answer (score 4):

The final sentence in your post, "*...what are good linguistic reasons to retain the heterographic homophones?*" reveals a fundamental misunderstanding on your part of what linguistics is.

1. Theoretical linguists, in their capacity as researchers, are never interested in prescribing any rules or maintaining or "retaining" anything. They are interested in making observations about how language works and how it changes over time.
2. Most linguists study spoken (or signed) languages; written records and orthography do come into play in linguistic research, but mainly as tools to gain insight into the historical development of languages.

In comments above you ask about a linguistics professor correcting spelling in written assignments. When I corrected my students' phonology assignments, I never cared if there were prescriptive grammar or spelling errors; I only wrote comments if there were errors having to do with the concepts being tested in the assignments. Think of a math teacher grading an assignment involving a geometric proof. Would that teacher take points off for an extraneous apostrophe in a sentence like "Because ABC is a right triangle, the square of it's hypotenuse is equal to the squares of the other sides"? Nope.

But actually, whether or not a linguistics professor corrects spelling errors in a written assignment is (as people have mentioned above) irrelevant. You bring up the scenario of an advisor correcting a thesis draft. In that case, the professor might comment on a misspelling, but **not in her capacity as a linguistic researcher!** Such a comment would merely be in the interest of "playing by the rules" of the academic establishment at large. When my choir director in college took us on concert tours, he dutifully saw to it that the underage members of the group (the majority of us) didn't drink after performances, as that is the law in the U.S. But his personal political belief was that people should be allowed to drink from the age of 18. It would be silly to extrapolate from my music director's behavior that there must be a "musical reason" for maintaining the legal drinking age of 21.

All that aside, I invite you to think about what you really mean when you lament the "bastardization of linguistic rules". The truth is, the way any individual uses language (written or spoken) can be seen as a "bastardization of linguistic rules" from the perspective of someone who lives in a different place or a different time. In my comment below your post I teased you about the dangling participle in your first sentence. Some people would consider that sentence construction to be a "bastardization" of English; as a linguist, I don't care one way or the other, especially since I had no trouble inferring your intended meaning. Even the spelling of *bastardization* that you use would be considered a bastardization of the written form of English by those in the UK who would spell it *bastardisation* (although their complaints would not be entirely founded from a historical standpoint--see [this blurb on -ize and -ise](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/03/ize-or-ise/))!

Comment: Well, to be fair, I asked it on english.stackexchange.com, and it was moved here perhaps errantly if this isn't a proper question of linguistics. Just as a side note, my Calc I, II, III and Advanced Geometry professor graduated from Harvard and would mark points off for incorrect spelling and punctuation, especially in geometry proofs.

Comment: Fair enough, on both counts! But it's not that this is the wrong place for your question. It's only the wrong place if you want experts in the field to take your side, haha!  Linguists will be happy that the question was asked here, and they (we) will be happy to tell you that the answer is "There are no good _linguistic_ reasons to retain those spelling distinctions."

Comment: Well, what good _reasons_ are there to retain the spelling distinctions then? Why don't we collectively abandon them today, informal and formal writing both, aside from 'because that's the way it was done before'?

Comment: Because changes to spelling and prescriptive grammar conventions are not precipitated in that way in our society. We might indeed abandon them if we lived in Communist China and a mandate were passed down from the ruling party that "from now on ther shall only be one 'ther' in written communications" (as they did when they [simplified the Chinese writing system starting in the 50s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Chinese_characters)).

Comment: Then what use was teaching 'spelling' in classrooms? Why not just teach the letters and leave it at "Okay, now sound it out. That's writing." What you seem to be getting at is that there are no real 'rules' to be upheld, merely conventions, and thus there's absolutely nothing 'wrong' with writing "that book over their".

Comment: There are rules, but they change over time--even within a lifetime. If and when I have a child, I will teach her the prescriptive rules of grammar and spelling (just as my English teacher mother did with me--that's how your dangling participle caught my eye), but I will adhere to the "rules" at that time, some of which will be different from the ones my mom taught me. And I will do so merely because I know that our society equates "correct" grammar and spelling with being "well-educated" and it will give her a leg up in the world.

Comment: So what it all boils down to, in effect, is for the 'appearance' of intelligence, then? This is the issue he hopes to challenge; that incorrect spelling and grammar ought to not reflect on a person's intelligence or education level, and yet the only real reason to follow them is to avoid "being perceived as a moron"?

Comment: Well, yes, I agree with your friend. I concede that a person's ability to pick up and adhere to the highly complex "rules" of spelling and grammar may reflect on her capacity to learn and think analytically in general, but there are many forms of intelligence, and many valuable minds can fall through the cracks if we use prescriptive spelling and grammar as a main metric for intellect.

Comment: I would just add that the reasons to keep the distinctions and resist any reforms (if _resist_ is the right verb to describe the situation in the "Anglo-Saxon world") might be better described as **extra-linguistic** rather than **linguistic**. It doesn't mean they are completely unimportant or irrelevant.

Comment: If the reasons are then **extra-linguistic**, where might I find reasons for perpetuating linguistically irrelevant traditions and customs such as there/their/they're? Are there none?

Answer (score 3):

The only reasons I can come up with are these:

- to avoid or reduce **semantic ambiguity**
- to keep tract of the word's **history**

In *Czech orthography*, for instance, we keep both <**y**> and <**i**>, and both <**ý**> and <**í**>, although their pronunciations have merged to [**ɪ**], and [**iː**], respectively, in most varieties of the language. While it helps the reader to distinguish <***bit***> "beaten" from  <***byt***> (both pronounced [**bɪt**]) "flat/apartment", and <***bít***> "to beat" from <***být***> (both pronounced [**biːt**]) "to be", it has a major impact on school children who have to **memorize** close sets of words preserving the <***y***>'s and <***ý***>'s.

Another example from Czech is the use of graphemes for **voiced** obstruents (such as [**d**], [**ɡ**], [**b**], [**z**]) in devoicing environments or their **voiceless** counterparts in voicing environments to maintain the *underlying **phonological*** information to some extent. This, unlike the <***y/ý***>/<***i/í***> distinction, can actually make things easier for learners, who usually retrieve the underlying information from the various inflected forms anyway, hence they know, for example, they have to write <***plod***> [plɔt] "a fruit", because the genitiv singular is pronounced [**plɔdu**], and they know they have to write <***plot***> "a fence", because the genitive singular is pronounced [**plɔtu**] etc.

So the answer is **not simple at all** and depends largely on **your preferences** as a reader or learner, as well as **various properties of the language** in question plus its **orthographical system**. Notice that one of the main obstacles Czech learners of English have to face is the high level of **spelling unpredictability** (spelling-to-pronunciation mapping and meaning-to-spelling choices) and I also remember reading an article mentioning the very same kind of problems pre-to-early-school native speakers of English have to face (which is why it seems to take them much longer to acquire basic reading and writing skills than it takes children trying to acquire a more predictable orthographical system, such as the Czech one). On the other hand, of course, learning the English spelling system **trains learners' memory**, which could be considered a pro rather than a con.

For what it's worth, being a non-native speaker (and forever a learner) of English, I would welcome a radical reform leading to a simplification and regularization of the English spelling system. :-)

Comment: From our discussion, he would discount the second point of keeping tract of the word's history, is irrelevant and just because it's how it has been done, does not mean it's the way it _should_ be done.

Comment: OK, to completely discard the history is something that a big portion of Czech linguists and intellectuals - and perhaps even the public - would oppose heavily. To some extent, it must be similar in other nations. The special spellings linked to the historical version of the words preserve the cultural identity and continuity. The number of examples in Czech is much  greater. Pavel hasn't mentioned "ů" vs "ú". Both are pronounced the same but "ů", with the circle above "u", is the long "u" which used to be spelled and pronounced "uo" - e.g. kuoň/horse. It evolved to "ô" (o with hat) in Slovak.

Comment: But even imported words such as president. We "mostly" spell it "prezident" in Czech these days because it has been pronounced in this way for quite some time - not only but especially thanks to the influence from Russia etc. But lots of intellectuals would insist on the spelling (and pronunciation!) "president" because it comes from the Latin "presedere". Every broken link to the ancient cultural languages turns us into savages more than before. Not everyone agrees with this concern but many people do and it's counterproductive to pretend that this concern does not exist.

Comment: @LubošMotl I completely agree with you, Luboš. Perhaps, my second point should have been more general: _to preserve **continuity**_. I think, however, it is also about a certain level of balance between "_preservationism_" and "_reformism_". Clearly, there are pros and cons on both sides. By _radical_ I don't necessarily mean _total_ in the sence of a 100% 1-to-1 mapping, anyway. I'm aware unifying <ie>, <ee>, <ea>, <ae>, <oe>, <eCV> etc. (all capable of representing /i/ in English) would already seem insurmountably radical to many preservationists. :-)

Comment: @PavelJetušek - exactly. It's always easier to be a reformer when the reformed object is some other nation's language (or its system), something we don't care about and we haven't grown an emotional tie to. But one should realize the expected reaction of a modest proposal, e.g. to bring English spelling closer to a pragmatic phonetic script. Hau meny Britnz end Emériknz vůd akčuely supórt sač a čendž θat is sou obvijsly dyzajreble. Hau many bougus konzrvatif argjuments agejnst θ refórm vůd be rejzd? Even to teač them  to write š e.g. in bullšit would be harder than it was for Mr John Huss.

Comment: The preservationism may also be justified by the need to preserve some mutual understanding between members of what used to be the same nation or language group. Languages and dialects are evolving all the time. With sufficient segregation, they are drifting in nearly random directions away from each other. Preservationism is really the attitude that should be thanked for the mankind's not having become a network of millions of mutually unintelligible dialects. Italians switched from "g" to "dž" intheir pronunciations but they still spell it as "g" - so they understand nations that still say G

Comment: We may have a little different view on this, Luboš. Another aspect of _preservationism_ not to be neglected is _dialect levelling_ or _dialect death_. I would generally prefer wider dialectal and linguistic variability; in fact, _millions of mutually unintelligible dialects_ should be much more valuable to linguists looking for "natural laboratories" or _language change_ and _language contact_.

Comment: As to your Italian example, are you sure? Is it not also because they're similar phonetically? It. <ginocchio> ~ Fr. <genou> / It. <manggiare> ~ Fr. <manger> etc.? I think it's a bit more complicated than what you propose here.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the Middle English Dictionary, you will see what English looks like when words are spelled according to the way they sound.

http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=178070811&egdisplay=open&egs=178073841

http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?size=First+100&type=headword&q1=suster&rgxp=constrained

Of course, words are spoken differently in different parts of a country and in different parts of the world, and pronunciation changes over time.

So, even if we could "decide" on a normalized spelling for each English word (New York accent wins?  London?  Los Angeles?) the spellings would eventually get out of sync with the sound, and for many speakers they would be out of sync from the get-go.

One also wants to preserve the ability to read what is already written.  Do you want people 100 years from now not able to read what is written today? How easy do you find Middle English?  or even Elizabethan English?

Comment: I understand **some** people might want to be able to read old texts (like myself), but how is that relevant to the **majority**? Moreover, now that we have spent some time in the computerized 21st century, I don't see why we shouldn't be able to (1) either _transliterate_ older texts or (2) _translate_ them if necessary, all within a relatively short transitional period, during which the two systems could coexist. You also seem to neglect _grammatical change_ and _semantic shifts_, which might have impacts exceeding those of phonological developments and orthographical reforms.